# Duplicate rows where column does not contain

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have data as below

I would like to duplicate the following columns: first name and last name where the profession(s) column doesnt contain  **N/A** value.

```
id  firstname   lastname    profession 1    profession 2    profession 3    profession 4    profession 5  
1   firstname1  lastname1   nurse           physician       n/a             n/a             n/a 
2   firstname2  lastname2   physician       nurse           n/a             n/a             n/a 
3   firstname3  lastname3   n/a             n/a             n/a             n/a             n/a 
4   firstname4  lastname4   nurse           n/a             n/a             n/a             n/a 
5   firstname5  lastname5   physician       n/a             n/a             n/a             n/a
6   firstname6  lastname6   nurse           midwife         physician       dentist         n/a 
7   firstname7  lastname7   physician       midwife         dentist         n/a             n/a
```

here is the sample output i needed.

```
firstname1  lastname1   nurse
firstname1  lastname1   physician
firstname2  lastname2   physician
firstname2  lastname2   nurse
firstname3  lastname3   n/a
firstname4  lastname4   nurse
firstname5  lastname5   physician
firstname6  lastname6   nurse
firstname6  lastname6   midwife
firstname6  lastname6   physician
firstname6  lastname6   dentist
firstname7  lastname7   physician
firstname7  lastname7   midwife
firstname7  lastname7   dentist
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Make a `hashmap`, which in PHP is array, and then combine the columns of `firstname` + `lastname` + all `profession` as the hashmap's key

Comment: If you just started to design the database, I do recommend you to normalize your data. Otherwise, you will end up with complex joins/queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way we unpivot in *MySQL* is to use `union all`.

```
select firstname, lastname, profession_1 as profession
from t
where  profession_1 <> 'n/a'
  
union all
  
select firstname, lastname, profession_2 
from t  
where  profession_2 <> 'n/a'

union all
  
select firstname, lastname, profession_3 
from t  
where  profession_3 <> 'n/a'

union all
  
select firstname, lastname, profession_4 
from t
where  profession_4 <> 'n/a'

union all
  
select firstname, lastname, profession_5 
from t
where  profession_5 <> 'n/a'

order by firstname, lastname
```

| firstname | lastname | profession |
| --- | --- | --- |
| firstname1 | lastname1 | nurse |
| firstname1 | lastname1 | physician |
| firstname2 | lastname2 | physician |
| firstname2 | lastname2 | nurse |
| firstname4 | lastname4 | nurse |
| firstname5 | lastname5 | physician |
| firstname6 | lastname6 | nurse |
| firstname6 | lastname6 | midwife |
| firstname6 | lastname6 | physician |
| firstname6 | lastname6 | dentist |
| firstname7 | lastname7 | physician |
| firstname7 | lastname7 | midwife |
| firstname7 | lastname7 | dentist |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9tcpxYfk?hide=4)